# how check if user is at the top of the html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu which I like to close automaticly if the user is at the top of the html page,how this can be done with javascript/jquery?

Comment: I believe `$(document).offset().top`, run an `if` on that, and if it's 0, call your function to close the drop down.

Comment: By capturing the `.scroll()` event and making a comparison in the callback function against `$(window).scrollTop()`

Answer (score 29):

You can easily do this with checking the [scrollTop](http://jqapi.com/#p=scrollTop) method from jQuery, on the window object:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

Just handle the scroll event and within the function, check $(window).scrollTop() === 0 and you will know if the user is scrolled to the top

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
   if($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
     $(".menu").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Can someone tell me the difference between `$(document).offest().top` and `$(window).scrollTop()`?